# How to duplicate structure field (of non-scalar structure) in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Suppose I have non-scalar structure

```
res = struct(); res(1).name = 'hello'; res(2).name = 'world';
```

Now I want to copy entire content of `name` field to another field, say `tag`.

Neither of the following worked:

```
>> res.tag = res.name;
Scalar structure required for this assignment.

>> [res.tag] = [res.name];
Insufficient number of outputs from right hand side of equal sign to satisfy assignment.

>> {res.tag} = {res.name};
 {res.tag} = {res.name};
           ↑
Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
[res(:).tag] = res(:).name;
```

or more simply, as you have discovered yourself:

```
[res.tag] = res.name;
```

The syntax with square brackets on the left-hand side is similar to that used for capturing several outputs returned by a function: `[out1, out2] = fun(...)`; see [*MATLAB special characters*](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/matlab-operators-and-special-characters.html#bvg3oy_-5).

Actually, the syntax `res.tag` produces a [comma-separated list](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html); and `[...]` is standard for *assigning* values to each element in one such list; see [*Assigning output from a comma-separated list*](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-7).

The right-hand side of the assignment should be another comma-separated list. If it is a single element, or you want to specify a list manually, you need [`deal`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html):

```
values = {10, 20};
[res.test] = values{:}; % works. {:} produces a comma-separated list
[res.test] = 10,20; % doesn't work. Use `deal`
[res.test] = deal(10,20); % works
[res.test] = 10; % doesn't work, unless `res` is scalar. Use `deal`
[res.test] = deal(10); % also works. 10 is repeated as needed
```

The reason why your attempt `[res.tag] = [res.name];` doesn't work is that `[res.name]` on the right-hand side concatenates the results of the comma-separated list `res.name` into *one* array, and so it's the same case as `[res.test] = 10;` above.

Comment: Great, how this can be explained? The following also worked `[res.tag] = res.name;`. We have array at the left and sequnce at the right.

Comment: @Dims With time it's something you "know" without even thinking about it. I guess the link is the best explanation: it's similar to how you call `[rows, cols] = find(...)` to capture two outputs of the function `find` for example

Comment: This is a simplified syntax that MATLAB developed shortly after introducing the `deal` function. It used to be `[res.tag] = deal(res.name)`, then they realized there is no ambiguity if you could leave out the `deal` call and do the assignment directly.

Comment: @Dims I've expanded a it on the explanation

Comment: @Cris Thanks for reminding me of that. I've included a bit on `deal`

Comment: I wonder why `[res.test] = 10,20` doesn't work, I noticed that recently too answering another question. I think it is because the comma separates statements, so it is `[res.test] = 10` as one statement, and `20` as the other statement. Nice answer!

Comment: @Cris Yes, that's exactly my interpretation too. In fact I just tried `[res.test] = eval('10,20')`. mostly for fun, but no luck